# Relation between AMRPDetail and AMProdItem

Tags: acumatica

The relation between the AMRPDetail record and the AMProdItem record seems to have changed in 18.206.  I'm looking for information on what it might be.  The inline comments in the AMRPDetail DAC say use the RefNoteID field but, I'm not sure which table that relates to.  It's NOT the AMProdItem table.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RefNoteID would relate to another table NoteID. So in your case most likely AMProdItem.NoteID or AMProdOper.NoteID which you can relate back to AMProdItem

Comment: Yep, AMProdOper was what I needed.  I tried to join it to AMRPDetail yesterday but, I only got back 34 records which I thought was too low.  Turns out, it's not.  Thanks Brendan!

Comment: No problem. The RefNoteID should join to other tables too depending on the planning record. Such as SOOrder.NoteID for example.